# Find Part of String in Different Sheet and Return Those Full Values in Other Sheet (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets in excel. One of like this. Name of this sheet is **sheet1**

[image]

Other like this. Name of this sheet is **sheet2**

[image]

I want to fill column **NAME** dan **ID** in **sheet1** based on **sheet2** Automaticaly with

Search part of string, like I just only typing **gesang** and excel outomaticaly fill **Gesang Nurhadi** and its **ID** in **sheet1**

But i don't know yet the formula to solve this problem. Anyone can help this?

Comment: A formula can be used, but the search string (text) you type need to be referenced from within the formula, therefore the result can not show in the same cell you're typing (unless you use VBA). If you type your value in column C values in colon A and B can be populated with a combination of INDEX and MATCH with wildcard search.

Comment: Without programming the closest you can come is to make a searchable dropdown list. and make a xlookup for the id. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wr-ns5vvpM